# Customising A Search Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, blogger

I would like to create a dropdown search bar; one similar to the search bar displayed on this blog http://www.theprivatelifeofagirl.com - it appears on the right hand side of the navigation bar. Essentially I would like a "search icon" to be visible alongside the existing icons, which the reader would then be able to click on and for the search bar to appear underneath the navigation bar.

I have tried to code together a somewhat similar search bar but I'm having some major difficulties. One of the issues is that I'm unable to make the icon image visible. I have it coded in the html however it ceases to appear on the blog. Another issue is that the search bar doesn't appear 'on click' instead it appears automatically - i.e when you refresh a page.

The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com

I have included the css coding below :

```
.show-search {
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
right: 95px;
display: block;
z-index: 10000;
}

.show-search #searchform input#s {
width: 150px;
background: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: karla, arial;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 10.9px;
color: #494949;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.09em;
padding: 7px;
}
.show-search #searchform input#s:focus {
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
#top-search {
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
width:80px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:0px;
}
#top-search a {
height:50px;
font-size:14px;
line-height:50px;
color:#343434;
border-left: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
display:block;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.search input#s {
border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
background: #fff url(http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/829C0943-C2A2-4052-BFF5-49E6606F44B6_zps3r9lpyvb.gif) no-repeat 96% 13px;
padding: 0;
font-size:11px;
color:#999;
letter-spacing:1px;
}
#searchform #s:focus { outline:none; }
```

The HTML coding is as follows :

```
<div id='top-search'>
  <a href='#'><i class='search'/></a>
</div>
<div class='show-search'>
  <form action='/search' id='searchform' method='get' role='search'>
    <div>
      <input id='s' name='q' placeholder='Search' type='text'/>
    </div>
  </form></div>
```

And the Javacript coding is as follows :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";
$('#top-search a').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.show-search').slideToggle('fast');
});
});
//]]></script>
```

Any input in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your html you need to add an image tag

```
<div id='top-search'>
<a href='#'>

//Need to an img here
<img src="url to image">

<i class='search'/>
</a>
</div>
```

As for your searching appearing automatically what you can do is change display to none.

```
.show-search {
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
right: 95px;
display: none;
z-index: 10000;
}
```